# Installer error (WiX): "Installation package could not be opened"

Tags: wix

Sometimes my WiX installer gives an error that looks something like:

> This installation package could not be opened. Contact the application vendor to verify that this is a valid Windows Installer package.

What does this mean? It looks like this is an error thrown by the msiexec program to indicate a corrupted install package or software.

Is there something we can do from a code/WiX perspective to handle this?...even though this seems to be more of a file corruption issue.

---

Here's what I see when I run this using msiexec verbose logging:

```
    === Verbose logging started: 10/16/2013  6:36:20  Build type: SHIP UNICODE 5.00.7601.00  Calling process: C:\Windows\system32\msiexec.exe ===
MSI (c) (3C:D8) [06:36:20:134]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

MSI (c) (3C:D8) [06:36:20:134]: Font created.  Charset: Req=0, Ret=0, Font: Req=MS Shell Dlg, Ret=MS Shell Dlg

MSI (c) (3C:24) [06:36:20:134]: Resetting cached policy values
MSI (c) (3C:24) [06:36:20:134]: Machine policy value 'Debug' is 0
MSI (c) (3C:24) [06:36:20:134]: ******* RunEngine:
           ******* Product: MyServer.msi
           ******* Action: 
           ******* CommandLine: **********
MSI (c) (3C:24) [06:36:20:134]: Incrementing counter to disable shutdown. Counter after increment: 0
MSI (c) (3C:24) [06:36:20:150]: Machine policy value 'DisableUserInstalls' is 0
MSI (c) (3C:24) [06:36:20:150]: Note: 1: 1402 2: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer 3: 2 
MSI (c) (3C:24) [06:36:20:150]: Decrementing counter to disable shutdown. If counter >= 0, shutdown will be denied.  Counter after decrement: -1
MSI (c) (3C:24) [06:36:20:150]: MainEngineThread is returning 2
=== Verbose logging stopped: 10/16/2013  6:36:20 ===
```

Comment: When do you get this error? When you build your installer or when you run it? Could you paste the entire error?

Comment: I get this error when I open the installer package..happens only on server machines.

Comment: Put ORCA on the machine and try editing the MSI.  Also try msiexec /I foo.msi /l*V install.log and post the log.

Comment: Here's the pop-up msg I see when I click on the installer: "This installation package could not be opened. Verify that the package exists and that you can access it or contact the application vendor to verify this is a valid Windows Installer package"

Comment: Orca: see *[Orca.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370557(v=vs.85).aspx)* (MSDN). A sample location for the installer for Orca is C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\Orca.Msi